# create hash from csv file gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I want to create a hash, from a CSV file which has bunch of data
my ruby file code is looks like

```
hersteller = Hash[CSV.read("db/red.csv", col_sep: ',', row_sep: :auto, headers: true).map {|row| [row["lieferant_nr"], row["beschreibung"]]}] #this is line number 45

 CSV.foreach("db/red.csv", col_sep: ',', row_sep: :auto, headers: true) do |row|  # map keys

  hash = Hash[row.map {|k, v| mapping[k] ? [mapping[k], v && v.strip.gsub("\u00A0", "")] : nil}.compact]  # ignore NULL values

  hash.reject! {|k, v| v == "NULL"}  # get hersteller names

  hash["hersteller"] = hersteller[hash["hersteller_nummer"]].strip.gsub("\u00A0", "") if hash["hersteller_nummer"].present? #this is line number 54
```

This gives me an error when i create hash

> > undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass
> >     /home/anish/helios/dynalink/db/seeds.rb:54:in`block in   top (required)>'
> >     /home/anish/helios/dynalink/db/seeds.rb:46:in   top (required)>'

Can anyone suggest me what's went wrong here....
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
hash["hersteller"] = hersteller[hash["hersteller_nummer"]].strip.gsub("\u00A0", "") if hash["hersteller_nummer"].present? #this is line number 54
```

to:

```
hash["hersteller"] = hersteller[hash["hersteller_nummer"]].strip.gsub("\u00A0", "") if hersteller[hash["hersteller_nummer"]].present?
```

you should be checking for presence of `hersteller[hash["hersteller_nummer"]]` and not `hash["hersteller_nummer"]`